# bash do loop with length of directory

Tags: bash, list, loops, directory, names

I am trying to loop through filenames within a directory so I can perform an operation on each.

I am able to loop through just 10 filenames if I use:

```
var=($(ls directory))
for k in {1..10}
do
    echo ${var[$k]}
done
```

Which gives me the first 10 filenames in my directory. However, I want to loop through them all.

If I do:

```
length=($(ls directory -1 | wc -l))
```

I get the length (for this example, it is 62)

So when I combine everything together:

```
var=($(ls directory))
length=($(ls directory -1 | wc -l))
for k in {1..$length} 
do
    echo ${var[$k]}
done
```

I get the error 'syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1..62}")

Any help to fix this, or a better solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is both powerful and limited.  Observe that it happens before any variables are expanded, so any attempt to use `{1..$length}` is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansion is performed by shell before variable expansion, hence you are getting the error.

You can use:

```
for k in $(seq 1 "$length")
```

to get around the problem.

---

Also what you are doing can be easily done by:

```
files=( * )
for i in "${files[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

or even simpler:

```
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply :

```
for file in *; do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "Do what you want with" "$file"; 
  fi
done
```

Comment: The one problem that neither your answer nor the other answer (as I type) deals with is that `ls directory` part.  Up to a point, using `directory/*` would work; it would give the names in a usable format (and `shopt -s nullglob` might be beneficial).  However, the `ls` command would give just `file` where `directory/*` would yield `directory/file`.  That can be dealt with (by `basename`, for example, or with minor caveats `${file##*/}`) in the loop.

Comment: Added a test to get files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Or: `(cd directory; for file in *; do ...; done)`

Comment: @rici: that's probably OK, unless the processing relies on being in the current directory at the start of each processing step, rather than in a distant directory.  Problems could relate to commands or files not found that would be found if the `cd` had not been done  Probably OK, but not guaranteed.